# How to make domain redirect?

Tags: php

So to make it simple:

Let say my domain is `greenexample.com`. Now using my domain, I want to make the link:

```
GreenExample.com/amazon321
```

Redirect to:

```
Amazon.com
```

Without using meta refresh.

I want to make multiple link re-directs like this.

So how do I do it in index.php, or do I need to create a new php file in my file directory for each link?

If so, what would the php code be to do so?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, I wasnt trying to involve folders or anything, I just thought you might have to make a folder named after the link? I just want to make certain buttons or words on my site go to a link, and mask it with my domain. So it re-directs. Essentially what the plugin http://www.wpwizardcloak.com/ does. But I dont want to use plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it with a PHP file, create an `index.php` file in the `amazon321` directory with the following:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.amazon.com");
exit;
?>
```

An alternative, and probably a better way, would be to use `Redirect` directives in your `.htaccess` file instead. (Assuming you're on a linux based server.)

```
Redirect /amazon321 http://www.amazon.com
Redirect /amazon123 http://www.amazon.com
```

You can even get fancier than this by using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) directives. For example, you could capture certain criteria in the URL and pass it on.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^amazon/(.*)$ http://www.amazon.com/$1 [R]
```

In the example, anything after `amazon/` is found and replaced where the `$1` is. So "http://www.greenexample.com/amazon/12345" would redirect to "http://www.amazon.com/12345".

Comment: But there is no amazon321 directory?? That would be a link. For instance, I want to highlight a word on my site, and link it to amazon.com. But I would mask it with: GreenExample.com/amazon321 which would re-ddirect to amazon.com.

Comment: With `Redirect` and `RewriteRule`, the file/folder doesn't (and probably shouldn't) actually exist on the file system.

Comment: Ah beautiful!  The Redirect one worked. But curious, is the "RewriteEngine On" better to use that the Redirect version? Is it faster or better for SEO or something? or does it not really matter?

Comment: The benefit of the rewrite example would be to write a single rule that would match several different URLs, as I have shown in the example.

Comment: oh, so its just a matter of convenience? So for speed in redirecting, it would not matter. Okay cool, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use header location

Code :

```
<?php
   header("location:http://www.Amazon.com");
   exit;
?>
```

You can show the javascript redirect

```
<?php
 echo "<script>location.href='http://www.Amazon.com'</script>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Create a file 'amazon321'. Your links click through to this. Put a redirect at the top of this page to amazon.com. So whenever someone ends up on this page they are automatically redirected